# action on button press and release

Tags: android

At the moment I have a toggle button which calls a method, if I press it the togglebutton gets disabled, code is ran and the button is re-enabled, if i press it again, same thing again, back to it;s original state. I want to change this so that when the button is held down it change state and runs the code, when i let go, it changes back. How can I do this? Can i set some sort of listener in this method, is that how it is done? So I set clicklistener in this method, on the handle tot he button, what is the button called here, do I have to give it a name to attach the listener to?

```
public void pushtotalk3(final View view) {

                //if more than one call, change this code
                  int callId = 0;
                  for (SipCallSession callInfo : callsInfo) {
                      callId = callInfo.getCallId();                      
                  }
                  final int id= callId;

        final boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
        ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(false);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (on) {
                        OnDtmf(id, 17, 10);
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        OnDtmf(id, 16, 9);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
                                ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_lightblue_glossy);
                                ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to send: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

EDIT: in particular I am wondering how to do this in the "method version" of using a button.
" instead of applying an OnClickListener to the button in your activity, you can assign a method to your button in the XML layout, using the android:onClick attribute"

Do I cast view to togglebutton and use that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    ToggleButton yourBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.yourbtnid)
    yourBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            switch (event.getAction()) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                                //press
                                ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
                                ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(true);


                                return true;
                            }
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                                //release
                                ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_lightblue_glossy);
                                ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(true);

                                return true;
                            }
                            default:
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                    });
```

Try this, if you want call with onClick method, but i dont promise anything:

```
public void touchButton(View view) {
       view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             switch (event.getAction()) {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                 //press
                 ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
                 ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(true);


                 return true;
             }
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                 //release
                 ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_lightblue_glossy);
                 ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(true);

                 return true;
             }
             default:
                 return false;
             }
        }
    });
    }
```

And put this into your XML item:

```
android:onClick="touchButton"
```

Comment: hello thanks for the answer, as far as I understand it there are two ways to reference your button, this method, or give the button a name in xml and call that method, i am wondering about the other version, where I call a  method name.

Comment: You can't call onTouch with XML attribute, you only can call onClick atribute from XML (android:onClick="nameAction") but no android:onTouch="actiontouch"

Comment: Oh that is a pity, I really like that method of doing things. Thanks

Comment: Trying your first method, why a re there errors if I place this code in the file, says expected "{". What are the rules for placement of the listener? And the definition of the button? Does that happen in onCreate?

Answer (score 1):

```
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

    }
}
    };
```

hope this will help u

Comment: thank you, good answer, I have edited my question with another question :)